# How can you explain the pKa of the first protolysis of phosphoric acid without using resonance

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, resonance

The pKa1 of phosphoric acid is [2.14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphoric_acid).
As far as I am concerned, **phosphoric acid does not have any double bounds** and, as a main-group element, obliges to the octet-rule. This does create formal charges but these are preferred over breaking the octet-rule. This is further explained in this [article](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/83484/most-contributing-resonance-structure-of-phosphoric-acid).

This begs the question though: **How can one explain the low pKa**.

**Resonance** seems to be off the table due to the fact that there cannot be any resonance if there is no conjucated system.

As far as I am concerned, **expanded octets are incorrect** and cannot be applied here - if they can even be applied anywhere since I believe this theory is somewhat outdated.

**Inductive effects** seem like they could be of use here since there are indeed 3 OH-groups and one O (the one with the negative-formal charge). But I believe that this should not be able to explain this pKa for two reasons.

First of all, all of these groups should theoretically **draw electron-density to themselves**. This would not make the bond between the H and O more unstable and thus **would not result in a higher chance of dissosiation of the proton**.

Furthermore, when comparing the pKa from the first protolysis of phosphoric acid to the one from ethanol (pKa=[15.9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethanol)) **the differnece seems to be far too great to be due to an inductive effect**.

Continuing this thought though, I have had the idea that maybe this **relativly strong pull of electon density** - due to the number of groups with a negative inductive effect -**could stabilise a negative charge**, thus making the first protolysis more appealing. A similar thought, but this time with the **polarizability of the phopshorusatom** in mind, is explored in the following.

Assume one or more protons have already been taken away, leaving behind a negative charge. The **elektostatic repulsion** of the bonding elektrons (and maybe others aswell) from this negative charge would **push the electron-density towards the comparibly high polarisable phosphorusatom**. This in turn could lead to a **somewhat stabilised negative charge**. Now I know that there is no "real" delocalisation to apply here - this is just a thought I have had.

I have also thought about something similar to the **erlenmyer rule**. My theory was that due to the multiple OH-groups on the same phosphorus there might be a similar reactivity as with carbonatoms with multiple OH-groups. But as far as the feedback I have recieved from discussing this posibility, this seems like a **far fetched assumption** and I have to agree.

The last idea has something to do with constitutional isomers (more specific:**tautomers**). H-Atoms are know for their behaviour to swap places. If, for example, one proton has already been taken away, the remaining H-Atoms could swap their place to the negative charge because of the electrostatic attraction. This would lead to a somewhat **delocalised proton** (or multiple protons) **leaving the the negative charge to be also delocalised** making it harder for it to accept a different proton (for example from water). (I believe the term "delocalisation" is misplaced here since there is no conjucated system and thus no resonance but I could not find a better way to describe it)

As you can see I am very confused but intrigued by this topic. Most of the sources I have looked at and professors + colleagues I have talked to, draw the phosphoric acid with a double-bounded O-Atom (oxo) and explain its pKa with resonance. This makes it incredibly frustrating to figure anything out about this. This is why I am searching for help here and sharing all of my thoughts - no matter how wrong some of them sound.
I hope somebody can help me - and others with a similar question -out.

Thank you

Comment: If you write a single or double bond there doesn't matter. Both oxygens are equivalent and charge is delocalised.

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/13796/nitric-acid-vs-chloric-acid-strength

Comment: But what about the octet? Shouldn't the ocetet-rule be valued over creating fromal charges? There are only four available AOs for phosphorus so it cannot have 5 bonds. The phosphoric acid is also not hypervalent as you can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervalent_molecule#Alternative_definition). I may be missing something but because of the non existent 5th bond I cannot comprehend there being any resonance. I am well aware that even the octet is only a law made up my us and thus doesn't depict the nature perfectly.

Comment: Think if dative bond to oxygen is any different then P-O- created in dissociation. You don't even need resonance.

Comment: @Mithoron I am unsure if I unterstand you correctly but I think you want to mention the difference between the coordinate bond (P-O) to the product of dissociation (P-O^-)? Because of the negative charge at the oxygen the dissociation of the next H is less likely. I do get the differing pKa's between phosphoric acid/dihyrogen-phosphate/hydrogen-phosphate. The problem I am having is explaining the first pKa in comparison to something like ethanol - the pka is way to low for a OH-group so there has to be something that explains it. If you meant something different please comment...Thanks

Comment: The answer there^ shows my point.